# Evaluating a recurring series in Octave using a while loop

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to evaluate the series ∑<sup>∞</sup><sub>*n*=1</sub> u<sub>n</sub> in Octave, using a *while* loop. The recurrence relation *u<sub>n+1</sub> = (u<sub>n</sub>)<sup>2</sup>* is provided.

The summation should stop when *|u<sub>n</sub>| < 10<sup>-8</sup>*.

So far this is what I got:

```
n=30
ser(1)=0.5;
sumser(1)=ser(1)
for k=1:n
    ser(k+1)=ser(1)^2;
end
for k=1:n
    while sumser(k)<10^-8
        sumser(k+1)=sumser(k)+ser(k+1)
    endwhile
end
```

I keep getting the error:

> error: addex: A(I): index out of bounds; value 2 out of bound 1
>
> error: called from
>
> addex at line 8 column 3

Comment: the line `ser(k+1)=ser(1)^2;` shouldn't be `ser(k+1)=ser(k)^2;`?

Comment: Yeah you're right. Though the error with line 8 persists.

Comment: also, the summation should stop when abs{u_n}<10^-8 or when the absolute value of the sum is less then 10^-8?

Comment: Where did you get `ser(1)=0.5` from? Is that specified in the series? Also why `n=30`?

Comment: Its the term value u_n, not the sum.

Comment: Hah crap forgot to mention the first term is 0.5

Comment: I just used n=30 for now. Would have increased later.

Comment: @Knack but you don't know what the limit is yet which is why you use a `while` loop. You really shouldn't need any `for` loops for this...

Comment: @Dan Yeah, that makes sense. I tried to base this off an example gave to me by a professor, using the `for` loop to define the series seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, then this should do the trick. There are too many problems with your code to address individually (unless I've misunderstood the question):

```
u(1) = 0.5;
S = u;
n = 1;
while (abs(u(n)) >= 10e-8)
    n = n + 1;
    u(n) = u(n-1)^2;
    S(n) = u(n) + S(n-1);
end
```

Comment: Thanks, works as it should. Think this is a way more logical approach.

Comment: just a small nit pick but it seems to me that a `do-until` loop would read even nicer than a `while`.

Comment: @carandraug That's really a matter of personal preference, I can't see any benefit it.

Comment: @Dan can you please clarify this for me, according to my limited knowledge 

`e=10^` i.e `2e-2 = 2*10^-2` with that in mind, since the limit was said to be `10^-8` shouldn't we then write `while(abs(u(n))<1e-8` instead of `while(abs(u(n))<10e-8` since `1e-8 = 1*10^-8 = 10^-8`? please read [here](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/another-issue-with-10-2.105407/)

Comment: @thembaalexkhumalo you might be right, I haven't used Matlab in a few years so I don't remember the exact syntax, and I don't have access to it to check now. But you'd definitely want `>=` not `<`

Comment: @Dan yes thanks, I made a typo there 

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing the question leads to an expression of the maximal index n complying with the condition  |u_n| >= Min with

```
u_0 = 0.5
Min = 1e-8
n_max = log(log(Min)/log(u_0))/log(2)
```

Then we have directly, without any slow while loop

```
Sum = sum(u_0^(2^(0:n_max)))
```

yielding

```
>> Sum = sum(u_0^(2^(0:n_max)))  
Sum  = 
   0.8164215
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to loop over n, but just vectorize your code. What you try to do is to sum a sequence until the element is smaller than a given tolerance (denoted as **tol**, and in this case is 10e-8). I assume that you would start with u(1)>0. Then, as long as u(1)<1 the process will eventually stop. Due to the recurrence relation, once u(1) and tol are pre-specified, we already know when to stop--when the u(n)>=tol but u(n+1)<=tol.Here is the code:

```
function s=sum_seq(u1,tol)
%tol is the tolerance. In your case, 10e-8
if(u1<0)||(u1>=1)
    disp('Error! Wrong choice of u(1)!');
    s=[];
else
    K=log10(tol)/log10(u1); %K=log_{u1}(tol) is an auxiliary variable
    n=floor(log2(K))+1; %It makes sure u(n)=u(1)^(2^(n-1))>tol>=u(n+1)
    A=u1.^(2^(0:n-1));
    s=sum(A);
end
```

Then, you  call get your result by running `s=sum_seq(0.5,10e-8)`. If you prefer not to use a function, then the four lines within the "else" part do the job. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another easier and intuitive way to solve this problem is to first get all the elements that will be in that series and then use the built in `sum` function to sum all of them up.

```
ser(1) = 0.5;
sumser = 0;
n = 1;

while(abs(ser(n)) >= 10e-8)

 ser(n+1) = ser(n)^2;
 n = n+1;
end

sumser = sum(ser)
```